# can't get the webcrawler going to loop through a list of URLs

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, csv, web-crawler

Python IDLE 2.7

I am trying to get all the company names from A - Z and save all the results into a csv file. Here's the first url http://app.core-apps.com/weftec2014/exhibitors/list/A

the following code works for every single page if i manually change the last letter of the url for 26 times, like http://app.core-apps.com/weftec2014/exhibitors/list/Z

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://app.core-apps.com/weftec2014/exhibitors/list/A')
page = response.read()
page = page[4632:] 


def get_next_target(page): 
    start_link = page.find("<a href='/weftec2014/exhibitors/")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    else:
        start_place = start_link+73 #to get company names after the first <div>
        end_place = page.find("</div>", start_place)
        item = page[start_place:end_place]
        return item, end_place

def print_all_com(page): #return company names
    results = []
    while True:
        item, end_place = get_next_target(page)
        if item:
            results.append( [ item.strip() ] )
            #print item
            page = page[end_place:]
        else:
            break

    return results


data = print_all_com(page)

import csv
with open('weftec.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

However I would like to let python loop through A - Z for me and return all the company names AT ONCE.
So I add another coding block below the previous script:

```
letter = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
url = 'http://app.core-apps.com/weftec2014/exhibitors/list/'

for n in range(0, len(letter)):
    target = []
    url_letter = url+letter[n]
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url_letter)
    page = response.read()
    page = page[4632:] 
    data = print_all_com(page)
    target.append(data)
```

I think there's something wrong with the script above since len(target) is 1 instead of the total number of the company from A - Z.

As I save the result into a CSV file, it gives me a pretty odd result, which is the company names on the Z page. See the exact result below.

```
['ZAPS Technologies, Inc']  ['Zoeller Engineered Products'] 
['ZAPS Technologies, Inc']  ['Zoeller Engineered Products']
```

I think the something went wrong in the second block but i couldn't really figure out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting target to an empty list on every iteration of that loop. Initalize target as an empty list outside of the loop first.

```
target = []
for n in range(0, len(letter)):
...
```

Comment: thanks. it works. I also changed target.append(data) to target.extend(data), which made the output so much prettier.

Comment: Yes, .append takes the entire data structure and appends it to the list, whereas extend takes the contents of the data structure and appends it to the end of the list. e.g. one gest [a,[b]], other gives [a,b].